# What methods exist for filtering air to alleviate allergies?

Tags: mold, health-and-safety, air-filter

I've found out that I have an allergy, especially for the mold. I live in a very wet climate, so it's a problem.

I was given advice to buy this [AIRFREE E60 air purifier](http://www.airfree.com/en-GB/Products/product-detail/Purifiers-for-the-Home--2/Airfree-E60-.aspx). But now I'm interested to know if there are any alternatives? How can I clean the air in my bedroom (~11 square meters) from the mold?

Comment: Is the AIRFREE E60 an [ioniser](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/8514/13251)? So it charges particles and then magnets attract them to some container? You may be interested in [this puzzle](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28293/ventilation-with-a-fan-during-allergy-seasons-carbon-filters-or-other-filter) with a tree close to a window so have to have good air-filters and still good airflow, dilemma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If mold is an issue in your house I'm not sure a furnace filter is really going to help, even a HEPA filter as all it will do is filter the air passing through the filter; it won't do anything to prevent the mold spores from entering the air where they are growing.

Generally the best solution to mold issues is to solve the moisture issue.  If you have any leaks (roof, pipes, etc.) then you need to fix those otherwise you'll never stop the mold growth.

If it is caused by high humidity then a dehumidifier would probably be a good investment.   Air conditioners dehumidify as part of their operation, so if you don't already have one it might be worth looking into adding one, alternatively if you already have one and it's not doing enough, a stand-alone dehumidifier can be used.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a dehumidifier. you need to solve the moisture problem.

Answer (score 2):

About any reasonably sized [HEPA filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEPA) unit should do the job for you.
There's huge price variations in the things, so looking for a unit w a decent fan motor, open cell foam pre-filter, and a low price is worthwhile.
If you're do-it-yourself capable, they're not all that hard to make using a store-bought HEPA filter replacement filter, [like this or similar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00007E7RW), some open cell foam, and a fan.