# What is the name of these silver curtains used to reflect heat energy back outside?

Tags: windows, cooling

Some people use aluminum foil to reflect heat on windows but I find it very depressing and bad-looking thing. My Chinese friends use [台州涂银反光窗帘布](http://detail.china.alibaba.com/offer/954609848.html) but I have no idea what it is in English: they translated it as a silver curtain and galvanized curtain. According to them, it is available at least in Beijing's IKEA and Shanghai's IKEA but apparently not in Europe or I just cannot find the right term to describe the special curtains to reflect the heat. This material is like a aluminum foil canvas but more durable. It is easy to use during travelling and studying particularly in places where you cannot carry a 30kg central-cooling unit like [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/28325/13251).

[image]

This is how it looks like on window: the side of sun is covered with this silver curtain and the other side to the room is the canvas knitted together. It is very hard to notice this unless you know what you are looking for but it keeps the room cooler and darker -- great!

[image]

**What is the name of the silver curtain? Which kind of factors should I consider in choosing a curtain? Which silver curtain reflect most heat and blocks well light?**

Comment: Is DMoore's answer what you are looking for?

Comment: @Masi thank you for curiosity, I have a feeling that there may be other terms desribing such curtains. I tried to summary some of my findings [here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/90231/13251).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Solar curtains](http://www.drleonards.com/Home-Furnishings/Windows-Walls/Solar-Curtains/29017.cfm#.UbAELJywWMA) - beware I haven't seen any that look much better than aluminum foil.

Comment: +1 for the term *solar curtains*, I could find very few products with the term, no wikipedia entry. Is solar curtains synonym with thermalogic window liner?

Answer (score 1):

I am summarising terms that may be able to work as *solar curtains* as pointed out by DMoore, I don't know yet whether solar curtains is a brand so listing alternatives below so easier to find curtains to block the heat.

1. Solar curtains (looks like curtains like in the picture, with style)
2. blackout, light-blocking curtain liner  (additional material added to curtains)
3. Outdoor 210*130CM Emergency Blanket Survival Rescue (not curtain but large enough and small enough to reflect heat)
4. 台州涂银反光窗帘布, as noted, my friend called this *silver curtain* and *galvanized curtain*. By the terms, I could find christmass decorations rather than curtains meant to reflect heat back outside.

where the translations are apparently not one-to-one. As pointed out in the comment, silver liner is related to [moon shining](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=silver+lining). So the way this has been done is apparently with 1. get some curtains and 2. get **blackout, light-blocking curtain liner** that you sew to the curtains.

Comment: (blackout; light-blocking) **curtain liner** (#2) (not a [silver lining](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=silver+lining), that's moon light though a cloud ;)